# Dafny. Pairs with bools do not equal

Tags: dafny

Why are these two failing in Dafny?

```
lemma test(x : (int, bool)) {
  assert x == (x.0, true) || x == (x.0, false);
}

lemma test''(v : int, x : (int, bool))
  requires x.0 == v; 
{
  assert x == (v, true) || x == (v, false);
}
```

https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/DtDMdm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this has to do with the internal boxing of booleans for the generic types that tuples can contain. In any case, here's a simple workaround:

```
lemma test(x : (int, bool)) {
  var (i, b) := x;
  assert x == (x.0, true) || x == (x.0, false);
}
```

Rustan